# How to assure acapella is in key with instrumental

Tags: key

I am a bit confused.
I always use a reference track, in order to create my chord progression, in this case it was:

I created the Chord Progression and then I used my own sounds of course, then I added a bassline and melody, with the help of captain plugins which allow me to create basslines and melodies always In Key.

According to Mixed In Key, the key of the reference track is 1A. (A-flat minor), according to Mixed in Key, the key of my track  is 2 A(E-flat minor).  Why the difference if I used the same chord progression?

After finishing the track  I searched for vocals labeled as Aminor on my collection.

However it looks like the vocal is not in key.

Here is the track without vocal:
https://soundcloud.com/valenciadjm/deep-in-london/s-lG47y

Here is the track with vocal:
https://soundcloud.com/valenciadjm/you-will-always-be-my-inspiration/s-O1rN3

My question is easy, any tips on workflow when working with vocals to be 100% sure the vocal is in KEY with the instrumental?
and 2nd. How much would I need to traspose the vocal up or down, to make it in key?

I appreciate your input here, this field is new for me.

Comment: Why not learn a minimum of theory about keys and chords? It's not that difficult to get a basic understanding. Google "diatonic chord sequences".

Comment: What is “mixed in key”?

Comment: @ToddWilcox "Mixed In Key is Windows and Macintosh software that simplifies a DJ technique called harmonic mixing. Mixed In Key analyzes MP3 and WAV files and determines the musical key of every file. Knowing the key, DJs can use music theory to play songs in a harmonically-pleasing order." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_In_Key

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question, but do you have Autotune? With Autotune you can force the vocals to fit any scale. The "home note" might get mapped to an unusual pitch of the target scale, but hey it's supposed to be creative, right? (send me half of the money after this trick makes you the number one creative DJ in the world)

Comment: Can you upload just the vocal or tell where to get it?

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "hire singers, making sure they can sing in tune."

Comment: When I click on your links I get "This track was not found. Maybe it has been removed".

Comment: the autotune vst seems to be great. sorry bout the track being  removed :(

Comment: The key of my track was Ab minor, the key of the vocal was Eb minor, I watched a video about the circle of fifths and learnt that I needed to traspose it down one semitone, and thats it.  thanks guys. https://soundcloud.com/valenciadjm/0013-you-will-always-be-my-inspiration/comment-728585465

Comment: You can answer your own question.  Maybe you should post that as an answer and accept it.  It will help the site's statistics and any future readers who have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The key of my track was Ab minor, the key of the vocal was Eb minor, I watched a video about the circle of fifths and learned that I needed to transpose it down one fifth, and that's it.

Comment: You mean a fifth for transposing your vocals, right? Transposing your vocals to D minor against an Ab minor backing track (or your backing track to G minor against Eb minor vocals) doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: trasposing the vocal down 1 semitone from Ebminor to Aminor https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+of+fifths&rlz=1C1GCEA_en-GBBE798BE798&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrj5Tkk5TkAhVPKewKHWQiAqIQ_AUIESgB&biw=1600&bih=708#imgrc=rYtXQNlQrj2MpM:

Comment: 1. The difference between spokes on the circle of fifths is a fifth, not a semitone. 2. I hope that's just a typo on your end, but I think you want to transpose the vocals to Ab minor, not A minor.

Comment: I just went ahead and edited it to say "fifth", because I'm pretty sure that's what was meant. If not, we probably need to have a second question about the circle-of-fifths versus semitones thing.